# Intuitive explanation in Window and SelectMany

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to understand the following example which combines `window` and `SelectMany`. As far as I know `Window` creates an `IObservable` stream (`IObservable<IObservable<T>>`) as soon as the `Observable` starts sending items. This stream is flatten with `SelectMany` to get `<IObservable<T>`.

In this [video tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Reactive-Extensions-API-in-depth-SelectMany) when using `SelectMany` in a simple `IObservable`, a new stream is created (let say a "thread"), where a function `f` is applyied.

Questions:

1. Could you please, cast some light, on how data arrived in the subscribe and what is the [marble diagram](https://jajeffries.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/using-marble-diagrams-to-understand-reactive-streams/) in accordance with the video tutorial?
2. What is exactly the function that is applied to flatten the stream?
3. Finally, is it possible to provide an more complicated example in which the `SelectMany` apply a simple function like `Range` and how the results are depicted in a marble diagram?

Thank you.

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))// start a counter from zero and last 100 milliseconds
        .Take(5) // take only the first 5 items  
        .Window(2)
        .SelectMany(c => c);

source.Subscribe(
    value => Console.WriteLine(value.ToString()),
    error => Console.WriteLine(error.Message),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Completed")
);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: "What is exactly the function that is applied to flatten the stream?" - Um, `SelectMany`. But Stack Overflow posts should really have *one* specific question in... at the moment this post is both too broad and unclear as to exactly which part you don't understand. Do you understand `SelectMany` in "regular" LINQ? You should be able to apply that knowledge here - and if you don't, I suggest that's where you should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marble diagram for each step of the code above is as follows:

```
interval: 0----1----2----3----4----5----6----7----
take5   : 0----1----2----3----4|
window  : W1--------W2--------W3|
 window1: 0----1|
 window2:           2----3|
 window3:                     4|
slctmny : 0----1----2----3----4|
```

`SelectMany` takes an observable of type `TSource`, and a selector function that transforms a single `TSource` object into a `IObservable<TResult>` object. It applies the selector function to all inputs, producing `IObservable<IObservable<TResult>>`, then flattens (merges) into one `IObservable<TResult>` objects. `.SelectMany(selector)` in Rx is pretty much the equivalent to `.Select(selector).Merge()`. So if you have a `SelectMany(o => o)` call, like your case, that's the same as a `Merge` call.

In our case, `Window` is returning `IObservable<IObservable<long>>`, so `TSource` is type `IObservable<long>`. The selector function returns `IObservable<long>`, so `TResult` is `long`.

Here's an example using `Range`: The selector will return observables that look like {0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3} etc., but `SelectMany` flattens it, so you get one observable: {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3...}

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))// start a counter from zero and last 100 milliseconds
        .Take(5) // take only the first 5 items  
        .SelectMany(l => Observable.Range(0, (int)l));
```